# how get the data starting from 1st month till current date in oracle sql between two dates

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

```
select count(EMP_ID) from EMPLOYEE
where created_date between trunc(SYSDATE) - (to number (to_char(SYSDATE,'DD')) - 1)  
and add_months(trunc(SYSDATE) - (to number(to char(SYSDATE,'DD')) - 1), 1) -1
```

But now I want to rewrite this query in such a way that it will always get data starting from 1st of month till created date. So for example if I run this query now I should get data from 1st January 2018 till 11th January 2018. AND i need to add one more date so that it will fetch from both from and to date .

If I run this query on 1st February then it will return data for entire month of January. I am not sure whether its possible to do in single query.

date format for e.g 22/10/2014

Answer (score 1):

A simple option is

```
select *
from employee
where to_char(created_date, 'yyyymm') = to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymm')
```

or any of its derivates, e.g.

```
where trunc(created_date, 'mm') = trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
```

---

However, if there's an index on `created_date`, it won't be used because of `to_char` or `trunc`. In that case, and if it matters (because performance suffers), you'd

```
where created_date between trunc(sysdate, 'mm') and sysdate
```

or even

```
where created_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
```

presuming that no row was created in the future.

---

If you need rows whose `created_date` is between two parameters, then you'd

```
where created_date between to_date(:first_date , 'dd/mm/yyyy')
                       and to_date(:second_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

presuming that values you entered are in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

Comment: hi littileffot thanks for update ,but i my date format is in dd/mm/yyyy format. And i need a query if i give two dates between that two dates it will fetch the query of that particualr months and dates.

Comment: I presume you're wrong. DATE datatype doesn't have any particular format; what you posted (DD/MM/YYYY) is just a format mask you use to represent date value (either by database's NLS settings, or TO_CHAR's format mask). If - on the other hand - you're storing dates as strings (into a VARCHAR2 column), you're doing it VERY wrong - switch to DATE as soon as possible. As of the next part of your comment: does it mean that you want to return rows whose CREATED_DATE is between 2 date values you enter as parameters? If so, have a look at edited answer.

Comment: Yeah right now I might not have the query correctly, but if I want to fetch the data between two dates using the above query you mentioned?

Comment: That's the last WHERE clause I posted.